# How to community contribute for WSO2 documentation?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to contribute in wso2 APIM documentation?

I have found in https://wso2.com/community but there is no information how to contribute in wso2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you could report it in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues with a suggested label : document